# How do you return ETH balance for account in hardhat test? (convert hex value into ETH value)

Tags: hardhat

How do you return ETH balance in hardhat test?

This snippet works but returns a BigNumber hex value.

```
const balance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(owner.address);
console.log(balance);
```

Comment: You can use ethers (https://docs.ethers.io/) library. 
ethers.utils.formatEther(Bignumber here)

Answer (score 1):

If the value is smaller than 64 bits, covert to a number: `balance.toNumber()`. If it larger than 64 bits, cast it as a string to avoid bigger numbers from being cut off: `balance.toString()`.

Comment: I think it's better to avoid using `.toNumber` unless you have a really good reason to. The way I think about this is: use bignumbers for everything except to print something or show something in a UI, and in that case convert the number to a string.

Answer (score 0):

ethers provides a function to format the BigNumber:

```
ethers.utils.formatEther(balance)
```

Link to docs (v5):
https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/display-logic/#utils-formatEther